# how to send a tcp request over a temporary VPN with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, vpn

Customer wants us to send a TCP notification to their servers from our network. But they demand it is over a VPN.

Is this a reasonable demand? Why not https/ssl?

How can you instantiate a VPN in c# code to send the request, and then close that vpn connection?

Comment: The usual TLS implementation only validates the identity of the server, a VPN means also validating the identity of the client (TLS *can* use a client certificate, but this is less common), also securing their network is much easier without opening up to the whole internet.

Comment: *Is this a reasonable demand?* - I think not really but perhaps they don't want to support any other way and I'm not sure what we could do about it; their network, their rules - *Why not https/ssl?* - why not indeed. If you think about it an SSL connection is basically akin to a temporary mini vpn